# Paypal express sandbox access deined

Tags: curl, paypal

I'm trying to use Paypal sandbox API and getting this response

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" on this server.

this is what im getting when the server tries to post data to paypal
```

Im using curl to post the data

Why is that ?

Comment: I think we are seeing the same problem. Our automated testing started complaining around 4:00 yesterday(3/3/14). I'm using the SOAP interface and sending to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr. I receive a response with HTTTP status 403(forbidden) and the data contains "Access Denied". I regenerated a new set of API credentials but it didn't change the response. There have been no changes to our PayPal code in over 6 months.

Comment: Have you had any updates regarding this issue? I am currently facing the same situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have contacted Paypal support and they said the problem is that i should not use the 
"**http**://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" Endpoint 
but use 
"**https**://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp" Instead

That solved my issue

Comment: Note: I am using `https:` and having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

The sandbox environment is set up to only allow HTTP 1.1 so you will get this access denied error if you are using HTTP 1.0.  The change to HTTP 1.1 was made a long while ago but was backwards compatible. However, in anticipation of these changes also coming to the Live environment, it was decided to turn off HTTP 1.0 support in Sandbox so that folks could properly test their integrations with HTTP 1.1.  You can review the following link that outlines the upcoming change in the Live environment to ensure that you are properly configured on your end.

https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=4283

Comment: Did You test it? What should I put in this 'host' header? They write on page You refer to that if You use HTTP 1.0, error will be 400 Bad Request...

Comment: It could also return a 400, yes. Using HTTP 1.1 without the Host header could return a 400 also. More information on the Host header can be found at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: I asked from what should I get header... I noticed 3 things: 1. problem is in fact caused by missing header 'Host'. 2. I need to put ANYTHING in this header and it works 3. FOR SOME TIME (if I remove header from request, response is still fine for a while... but later error come back :/