# Paypal SANDBOX SetExpressCheckout stopped working

Tags: php, api, paypal, sandbox

For some reason, when I try to connect to paypal sandbox API and do SetExpressCheckout using my XAMPP server it fails.
I turned error reporting on and this is the message I get:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
```

I've done some tests and it just does not make sense:

1. I can connect to the live API with correct credentials.
2. I can connect to the live API with incorrect credentials.
3. I **cannot** connect to the sandbox API with correct or incorrect credentials.
4. I can connect to live API and sandbox API using web browser using correct or incorrect credentials.
5. If I put in an invalid website name, it gives me a different warning (below).

Warning:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

So why is it that when I connect to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/ using my local server there is no response? I have not changed the code and it still works with Paypal live so what's going on here suddenly?

Comment: I'm using `https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp/` to connect to the live Paypal API and `https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/` to connect to the sandbox API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From March 25 PayPal doesn't support HTTP/1.0, [see details here](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details?eventId=4283). You can find helpfull [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172829/paypal-express-sandbox-access-deined)

Comment: Great! Thanks for that. I added `'protocol_version' => 1.1,` to my stream_context_create() and added `Connection: Close` to my header and it worked fine!